req.session not updated after saving them and sending an axios post request
so I am working on my login system, and if a user clicks a link which takes them to another page and their session has expired, it will simply get them to login again and after redirect to that page. However if that user has not clicked a GET link, and instead a POST link, I want it to also go to the login page, I do this all with middleware:
const isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
    if (req.session.userId) {
        // If userId exists in the session, consider the user as authenticated
        next();
    } else {
        const randomID = utils.randomString(10);

        const options = {
            method: req.method,
            url: req.originalUrl,
            body: req.body,
            query: req.query
        
        };

        postRouteStore.set(randomID, options);

        // If userId does not exist in the session, redirect the user to the login page
        res.redirect(`/login?redirect=${randomID}`);
    }
}; 

As you can see I set the data in a map, and then here is where I access it (in the login post route):
// Set the userId in the session
        req.session.userId = user.userID;

        req.session.cookie.maxAge = req.body.rememberMe && req.body.rememberMe === "on"
            ? 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 30 days for "Remember Me"
            : 1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // 1 day if "Remember Me" is off
        req.session.save();

        if (req.body.redirect) {
            if(req.body.vaID) {
                let membership = await prisma.membership.findFirst({
                    where: {
                        virtualAirlineID: req.body.vaID,
                        userID: user.userID
                    }
                });
                if(membership) {
                    return res.redirect(`/va/${req.body.vaID}/dashboard`);
                }
            }

            const requestId = req.body.redirect;
            const opts = postRouteStore.get(requestId);

            if (opts) {
                if (opts.method === "GET") {
                    res.redirect(opts.url); // Redirect to the stored request
                } else {
                    // Get the session cookies from the original request
                    const sessionCookie = req.session;
                    console.log(sessionCookie);

                    axios.post(`http://localhost:3000${opts.url}`, opts.body, {
                        headers: {
                            // Forward the original request's session cookie to the new POST request
                            Session: sessionCookie // req.headers.cookie contains the session cookie
                        }
                    })
                    .then(response => {
                        // Send the result of the POST request back to the user
                        res.status(response.status).send(response.data); // Send the actual response data
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('Failed to retry POST request:', error);
                        res.status(500).send('Internal Server Error');
                    });
                }

                // Clean up: remove the request from the store
                postRouteStore.delete(requestId);
            } else {
                res.redirect('/dashboard'); // If no stored request, redirect to a default page
            }
        } else {
            res.redirect('/dashboard');
        }

I have tried with Cookie, and others instead of Session in headers when I do the axios request, but absolutely nothing is working, if I were to log the req.session in the login route (second snippet) then it would show the correct info, however should I do it in the middleware, then it simply gives info not containing the new info.
I am stumped as to why this is happening, if I redirect as normal then it works perfectly fine and the info is there. But I cannot seem to find a way to get the new info to be there in the middleware.
Thanks
